# An error occurred while doing astype('datetime64[ns]')

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Subject has two rows. The fist column is time.

```
11:46:36 ......
12:0:4.......
```

What I am trying to do is

```
Subject['Time'] = Subject['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
Subject['Time']=Subject['Time'].dt.time
```

It does well for the first row and it gives me

```
2020-05-18 11:46:36
```

But when I want to do that for the second row it gives me the following error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 12:00:04
```

I know pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, and thus the timespan can be represented using a 64-bit integer which is limited to approximately 584 year.

When I do `Subject['Time'].dtype` it simply gives me `dtype('O')`

Comment: The type _date_time combined date and time. If you do not provide the date part explicitly, it is assumed to be 1-01-01, which is probably 1901-01-01. You have to add the date or use some other time units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of date and timedelta to add a custom date, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['11:46:36', '12:0:4']})

# to datetime object; add a custom date, e.g. 2020-05-18:
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime('2020-05-18') + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
# df['Time']
# 0   2020-05-18 11:46:36
# 1   2020-05-18 12:00:04
# Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` is not an appropriate datatype for data that does not have the "date" part. You probably want to use `timedelta` instead:

```
pd.to_timedelta(Subject["Time"])
#0   11:46:36
#1   12:00:04
#Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is a problem with time delta as well. Later in my code, I am comparing this time with another data time. Should I change it to time delta, I wouldn't be able to do the comparison.  I was wondering if you can modify to your answer which also includes data time. That data time however has this format datetime.time(14, 5, 8, 269000). Which as you can there is no data in this once as well

Comment: a timedelta alone doesn't seem much more useful to me either - delta to what? start of the day? again, that would involve some date. of course this all depends on what you intend to do with the data on the long run.